# Web-Server vs. Socket

Tags: sockets, server, webserver

I think this is an absolutely a beginner's question. But I still want to ask:
What is the difference between a Socket and Web-Server? And when A socket is sufficient and when we need a web server?

Comment: A Web server is where your files etc are all hosted and handles http requests etc and a socket is used on the machine to listen for traffic and receive data, you address the socket and port to send your data from your machine to the server.

Comment: So, there is no technical difference between them?

Comment: The socket references a physical area on your machine, for example when you setup a socket you define the port number where it listens on that machine and it's ip address of the machine is how u access it, so the socket makes it accessible on the network like a mailbox and the webserver is passed traffic from the socket that is accepted so as someone sends a request for a document the webserver listens on a socket for that traffic and can send a response over the socket to the connected machine.

Comment: I guess the best analogy is the socket being like a mailbox accepting mail and the Web server then handles whatever mail is passed into it if it's relevant to the Web server such as get, post requests etc.